# in PHP how do you process a HTML select box filled with times and exclude those already in MySQL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to populate a table with times the client has booked an appointment(eg. 10:30AM)
so I have a select box with the times of the day starting from 9:00AM to 7:00PM going up in 15minute steps(9:45am, 10:00am).

```
<select name="times">
<option value="09:00">9:00am</option>
.....
<option value="19:00">7:00pm</option>
</select>
```

I need to some how delete some of the times that are already stored in the database

would this be like?:

```
<?php
$times = $_POST['times'];
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'salon')
or die('error conneting to mysql');

$query = "SELECT times FROM `clients` WHERE `times` = '$times'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
<select>
<?php
$times = array('09:00','09:15', ..... '19:00');
foreach($times as $time);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
 if($row = $time){
unset($time);

echo '<option value="$time">$times</option>';
}
else{ echo 'oh no';
}
?>
</select>
```

well something like that.. anyway I just can't figure it out.

thanks in advance to all help.

P.S I know my code should be more clean and include strip_tags()          mysql_real_escape_string().
this is just for the purpose of asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally premature example of a code. There are a lot of errors in your code. BTW following is the correct one :

`$times = $_POST['times'];`

is an array so you can't use it like a string. You have to implode the array using comma (,) separator so that your variable $times could be like this

`$times_array = "in('09:00','09:30')";`

Following is full example

```
<?php

    $times_post = $_POST['times'];

    $times_array = "in('09:00','09:30')";// This will be your string after imploding post array

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'shiv')  or die('error conneting to mysql');

    $query = "SELECT times FROM `clients` WHERE `times` = $times_array";


    $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    echo "<select>";

    $times = array('09:00','09:15','19:00');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){

        foreach($times as $key => $time){

            if($row[0] == $time){
                unset($times[$key]);

            }else{
                echo 'oh no';
            }
        } 
    }

    $updated_times = array_values($times);

    for ($index = 0; $index < count($updated_times); $index++){
        echo "<option value=$updated_times[$index]>$updated_times[$index]</option>";
    } 

    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: yeah that code was just off the top of my head.. I should have tried it first, but thank you .

Comment: If you find that the answer is sufficient can you please accept it.